# VPC peering connection not routing to VPN subnet

Tags: networking, amazon-vpc

I am not sure if this is normal, but, I have a jumphost in one VPC, to which VPN connect to. All the hosts in this VPC subnets can reach the VPN clients.

This VPC is peered with another VPC, and none of the hosts in the peered VPC are able to reach the VPN clients at all, nor the VPN clients are able to reach the peered VPC.

If I tcpdump in the jumphost and attempt to connect from anywhere in the peered VPC to an VPN client, I see nothing, which means that the peering connection isn't routing anything that goes to the VPN client subnets.

Is this normal behaviour? Can it be fixed somehow?

That's the route table of the peered VPC. 10.14.89.0/24 is the VPN client subnet. VPN server is running in the 172.20.0.0 subnet in the other VPC.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, looks like it actually can't be done:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/invalid-peering-configurations.html

Comment: Which of the bullet points in the link apply to your case? I read them all and I didn't get it.